# creating divs and adding text through a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a set of sentences and radio buttons that I need to display on a webpage using a javascript function. I also need to create some divs to help me visually group these sentences on the webpage accordingly. I have written the function and I can display the sentences and radio buttons as shown below in the code below. I have also specified the divs:

```
var div1 = document.createElement("div");
div1.setAttribute("align","left");
div1.style.border = "1px solid #ccc";

var div2 = document.createElement("div");
div2.setAttribute("align","left");
div2.style.border = "1px solid #ccc";

var div3 = document.createElement("div");
div3.setAttribute("align","left");
div3.style.border = "1px solid #ccc";

var div4 = document.createElement("div");
div4.setAttribute("align","left");
div4.style.border = "1px solid #ccc";

var div5 = document.createElement("div");
div5.setAttribute("align","left");
div5.style.border = "1px solid #ccc";

var div6 = document.createElement("div");
div6.setAttribute("align","left");
div6.style.border = "1px solid #ccc";

var Sent1 = "Sentence 1 displays here";

var Sent2 = "Sentence 2 displays here";

var Sent3 = "Sentence 3 displays here";

div1.appendChild(div2);
div1.appendChild(div3);
div1.appendChild(div4);
div1.appendChild(div5);
div1.appendChild(div6);

div2.appendChild(Sent1);
div2.appendChild(Sent2);
div3.appendChild(Sent3);
div4.appendChild(Sent2);

return div1;
```

What I am expecting to see is 6 different boxes (divs) displaying on the page, with div2 (the second top most box on the page) having 2 sentences displayed within it (Sent1 and Sent2), div3 and div4 having one sentence displaying each, while the rest of the divs do not contain any text. 
Unfortunately, this is not what is displaying. What am I missing? Could someone please help me with the correct syntax/ approach?

Comment: Please, make a working jsfiddle.com to view the problem. In your code seems to left various function declarations and there is a lot of problems and errors in the code because is not the entire code ( I think)

Comment: I think you should append `div1` to an existing element before trying to append other elements into it.

Comment: The code does not work when I start to do the appends. I think that is where the problem lies. I need code to help me create 6 divs and add different text (sentences) within those 6 divs.

Comment: Replace `var Sent1 = createSentences("Sentence 1 displays here");` with `var Sent1 = document.createTextNode("Sentence 1 displays here");` do this for each `Sent1` / `Sent2` / `Sent3`. If you open your browsers console you will see this error `Uncaught TypeError: document.createSentences is not a function` unless createSentences is a function of your own? If so it would be a good idea to show that as it's relevant to the question. You will also want to append your first element in order to see everything else you're placing inside of it. `document.body.appendChild(div1);`

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not the entire code. I have another createSentences function that I created that I am calling here that works just fine. I have edited the code to remove that since it is confusing. I need help with creating the divs and the appending syntax please.

Comment: As I have already pointed out. You aren't appending the first div `div1` to anything so you won't see `div1` or the content inside of it. If you have any other issues then I recommend you display your `createSentences()` function as it could be in relation to the error.

Comment: @NewToJS I am able to display div1 with the sentence inside of it. The issue is no in case I want to display a second sentence within that same div1 that already has one sentence displayed within it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Where are you appending `div1` to something? It isn't in the source code you have showing here. If you want help please display all relevant source code. We can only go by what you show us. If you have other things going on that we can't see, how do we know that isn't the reason for this not working as intended... Sorry but I'm here to help, not play guessing games. Update your question with the relevant source code if you would like me to continue debugging.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly this is the problem:

you want to add some content in 6 different divs and in the second one add 2 content and in the third and fourth only one content for each.

Like this structure:

- div1
- div2

  - sent1
  - sent2
- div3

  - sent3
- div4

  - sent2
- div5
- div6

If this is correctly then you can edit your code to do that:

```
    var div1 = document.createElement("div");
    div1.setAttribute("align","left");
    div1.style.border = "1px solid #ccc";
    // i add some height to show empty boxes
    div1.style.height = "30px";

    var div2 = document.createElement("div");
    div2.setAttribute("align","left");
    div2.style.border = "1px solid #ccc";

    var div3 = document.createElement("div");
    div3.setAttribute("align","left");
    div3.style.border = "1px solid #ccc";

    var div4 = document.createElement("div");
    div4.setAttribute("align","left");
    div4.style.border = "1px solid #ccc";

    var div5 = document.createElement("div");
    div5.setAttribute("align","left");
    div5.style.border = "1px solid #ccc";
    div5.style.height = "30px";

    var div6 = document.createElement("div");
    div6.setAttribute("align","left");
    div6.style.border = "1px solid #ccc";
    div6.style.height = "30px";

    var Sent1 = document.createElement("p");
    Sent1.innerHTML="Sentence 1 displays here";

    var Sent2 = document.createElement("p");
    Sent2.innerHTML="Sentence 2 displays here";

    var Sent3 = document.createElement("p");
    Sent3.innerHTML="Sentence 3 displays here";

    //it is not possible to append same child to different divs than duplicate the div to append multiple times
    var Sent4 = document.createElement("p");
    Sent4.innerHTML="Sentence 2 displays here";

    div2.appendChild(Sent1);
    div2.appendChild(Sent2);
    div3.appendChild(Sent3);

    //appendChild move divs not copied
    div4.appendChild(Sent4);

    document.body.appendChild(div1);
    document.body.appendChild(div2);
    document.body.appendChild(div3);
    document.body.appendChild(div4);
    document.body.appendChild(div5);
    document.body.appendChild(div6);
```

Like you see in the code above, i add some comments because you try to use appendChild in the wrong way:

- **appendChild** only moves some existing dom node from a place to another place but not copy to another place;
- to show the **empty boxes** div on the page i add some **height** to the div but this is only useful to visualize the div if is without any content;
- i append child divs (div1 to div6) like childs to the body element, but you can append divs to anyone dom element based on your need;